# Using web3.py to filter previous transactions by swap, returns empty array

Tags: uniswap, web3.py, logs, swaps

I am using the web3 python package to filter transactions using the transfer function. The issue is no matter what I try to do, w3.filter.get_all_entries() returns an empty array. Any ideas as to why this is please?

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('blabla')

uniswap_router_address = w3.keccak(text="0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D").hex()
swap_event_topic_hash = w3.keccak(text="transferFrom(address,address,uint256)").hex()
contract_address = "0x2C5BC2Ba3614fD27FCc7022eA71d9172E2632c16"

event_filter = w3.eth.filter({

    # "fromBlock": 0,
    # "toBlock": "latest",
     "address": contract_address,
     "topics": [uniswap_router_address, swap_event_topic_hash]
})

logs = event_filter.get_all_entries()
```

I have tried all manner of things in the "topics" arguments, including getting rid of all of them and just trying to return all entries without a filter - to no avail.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Encoding doesn't seem to be the problem.

Pull the logs in and then filter by the topics if having issues:

```py
>>> logs = w3.eth.get_logs({'fromBlock': 18000000, 'toBlock': 'latest', 'address': contract_address})
```

I can't see that topic on the events page at that address so maybe there is nothing for you to filer for.

To filter for swaps it's best to use events from the pool contract.
A different way to approach might be:

```py
SWAP_TOPIC = w3.solidity_keccak(['string'],['Swap(address,address,int256,int256,uint160,uint128,int24)']).hex()
POOL_ADDRESS = '0x0318170609141BfDb38d20D1F1C5b5197670ECEE'
POOL_ABI = '''
[{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Burn","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"name":"Collect","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"name":"CollectProtocol","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"paid0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"paid1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Flash","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNextOld","type":"uint16"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNextNew","type":"uint16"}],"name":"IncreaseObservationCardinalityNext","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int24","name":"tick","type":"int24"}],"name":"Initialize","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Mint","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol0Old","type":"uint8"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol1Old","type":"uint8"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol0New","type":"uint8"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol1New","type":"uint8"}],"name":"SetFeeProtocol","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0","type":"int256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1","type":"int256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int24","name":"tick","type":"int24"}],"name":"Swap","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0Requested","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1Requested","type":"uint128"}],"name":"collect","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0Requested","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1Requested","type":"uint128"}],"name":"collectProtocol","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"fee","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint24","name":"","type":"uint24"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"feeGrowthGlobal0X128","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"feeGrowthGlobal1X128","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"flash","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNext","type":"uint16"}],"name":"increaseObservationCardinalityNext","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"}],"name":"initialize","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"liquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"maxLiquidityPerTick","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"observations","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"blockTimestamp","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"int56","name":"tickCumulative","type":"int56"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"secondsPerLiquidityCumulativeX128","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"initialized","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint32[]","name":"secondsAgos","type":"uint32[]"}],"name":"observe","outputs":[{"internalType":"int56[]","name":"tickCumulatives","type":"int56[]"},{"internalType":"uint160[]","name":"secondsPerLiquidityCumulativeX128s","type":"uint160[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"positions","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthInside0LastX128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthInside1LastX128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"tokensOwed0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"tokensOwed1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"protocolFees","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"token0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"token1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol0","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol1","type":"uint8"}],"name":"setFeeProtocol","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"slot0","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tick","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationIndex","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinality","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNext","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"unlocked","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"}],"name":"snapshotCumulativesInside","outputs":[{"internalType":"int56","name":"tickCumulativeInside","type":"int56"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"secondsPerLiquidityInsideX128","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"secondsInside","type":"uint32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"zeroForOne","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amountSpecified","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceLimitX96","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"swap","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1","type":"int256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int16","name":"","type":"int16"}],"name":"tickBitmap","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"tickSpacing","outputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"","type":"int24"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"","type":"int24"}],"name":"ticks","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidityGross","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"int128","name":"liquidityNet","type":"int128"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthOutside0X128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthOutside1X128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"int56","name":"tickCumulativeOutside","type":"int56"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"secondsPerLiquidityOutsideX128","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"secondsOutside","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"initialized","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"token0","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"token1","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
'''
pool = w3.eth.contract(address=POOL_ADDRESS, abi=POOL_ABI)

logs = w3.eth.get_logs({'fromBlock': 18000000, 'toBlock': 'latest', 'address': POOL_ADDRESS})

for log in logs:
  for topic in log['topics']:
    if SWAP_TOPIC == topic.hex():
      swap = pool.events.Swap().process_log(log)['args']
      print(f'[+] {swap}')
```

```
[+] AttributeDict({'sender': '0x3fC91A3afd70395Cd496C647d5a6CC9D4B2b7FAD', 'recipient': '0x3fC91A3afd70395Cd496C647d5a6CC9D4B2b7FAD', 'amount0': 59181093043759376125862899817, 'amount1': -144507509090164721, 'sqrtPriceX96': 124340099410697033872877, 'liquidity': 65619319847109989132266074, 'tick': -267310})
[+] AttributeDict({'sender': '0xDef1C0ded9bec7F1a1670819833240f027b25EfF', 'recipient': '0xDef1C0ded9bec7F1a1670819833240f027b25EfF', 'amount0': 730528137114137091707973967583, 'amount1': -1751005903786899877, 'sqrtPriceX96': 122225951006966288406232, 'liquidity': 65619319847109989132266074, 'tick': -267653})
```